# Applying custom ordering to lists (to sort a list of lists)

Tags: list, sorting, haskell

There's an example of how to sort a list with a custom ordering at this page:
http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputlist/sortBy_f.html

```
xxx a b  | odd a = LT
         | otherwise = GT

Input: sortBy xxx [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] 

Output: [1,3,5,7,6,4,2]
```

The standard less than order lets me compare lists, e.g.

```
[1,2,3] < [0,4,5]
```

Is False. But this doesn't work with the above example function:

```
Main> xxx [1,2,6] [1,7,3]
ERROR - Cannot infer instance
*** Instance   : Integral [a]
*** Expression : xxx [1,2,6] [1,7,3]
```

Is there an easy way to extend such an order to lists?

The reason I want this functionality is to use sortBy to sort lists of lists using my custom ordering.

I'd be grateful for example solution code, advice on what to read up on, or anything in between. I'm hoping there's some built-in way to do this with the language rather than write a function that compares the lists directly.

Comment: Note that `sortBy` expects the ordering function to define a [total order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order), which `xxx` does not. For example, `xxx y y` should return `EQ` for any `y`, and if `xxx y z` returns `LT` for some `y` and `z`, then `xxx z y` should return `GT` and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert a comparison function to a comparison function for lists with the code:

```
import Data.Monoid (mconcat)
compareList :: (a -> b -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [b] -> Ordering
compareList _ [] [] = EQ
compareList _ (_:_) [] = GT
compareList _ [] (_:_) = LT
compareList comparer (x:xs) (y:ys) = 
    comparer x y `mappend` compareList comparer xs ys
```

Now you can use `xxx` on two lists:

```
> compareList xxx [1,2,6] [1,7,3]
LT
> compareList xxx [2,2,6] [1,7,3]
GT
```

You could then use that to sort nested lists using your comparer:

```
> sortBy (compareList xxx) [[2,2,6], [1,7,3], [1,1,1]]
[[1,7,3],[1,1,1],[2,2,6]]
```

Comment: I don't think this works when the lists have different lengths.

Comment: @dave4420: You are totally right, it should be fixed now (longer lists where the rest of the list is the same are now greater than the shorter list). Good catch.

Comment: You imported `mconcat` instead of `mappend`. Nowadays, it's popular to use `<>` instead of `\`mappend\``.

Comment: But in fact, maybe you really did mean to import `mconcat`. Because then you have this simpler way of writing `compareList`, and with a slightly more general type: `compareList :: Monoid c => (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> c; compareList c xs ys = mconcat $ zipWith c xs ys`

Answer (score 1):

To replicate the behavior of `<` you would have to make your `xxx` function part of a type class. This is probably not worth it.

Instead, consider writing a new version of `xxx` specifically for lists:

```
xxxl :: Integral i => [i] -> [i] -> Ordering
xxx1 [] [] = EQ
xxxl [] _ = LT
xxxl _ [] = GT
xxxl (l1:_) (l2:_) | odd l1    = LT
                   | otherwise = GT
```

You might want to handle empty lists in some other fashion. This also illustrates why you cannot automatically generalize your `xxx` function to lists: how *would* you handle empty lists? You have to answer this question somehow, and writing a new function for lists is the easiest way.

You can now use your `xxxl` function with `sortBy` to sorts lists of lists: `sortBy xxx ...`.